# IOS App suggest twitter friends to users?

Tags: ios, twitter, twitter-oauth

Hi i have been searching for a while for this i want to implement a feature where if a user login my app through twitter she sees who she follows on twitter who  already joined my app and gives her the opportunity to follow them on my app like Meerkat does for example.Im using rails for my backend if that healps.
Any help pointing me to right direction is much appreciated.

(PS: Linkedin does it with email but Im interested with only twitter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after some more researching i found out that meerkat uses https://get.fabric.io/ to the best of my knowledge. im going to try it.